# When we print the document in full screen mode System.AccessViolationExcpetion has thrown. Platform : UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

When we add UI element in the AddPages() method of PrintDocument (Windows.UI.Xaml.Printing.PrintDocument), the System.AccessViolationException has been thrown.

Note : The same code works fine when we print the document in PreferredLaunchViewSize mode. If we print the document in FullScreen mode the exception thrown.

Code snippet:

```
PrintDocument printdocument = new PrintDocument();
Dictionary<int, UIElement> printPreviewPages = new Dictionary<int, UIElement>();
Canvas print = PrintPanel.Children[i] as Canvas;
if (printPreviewPages.Count < i + 1)
   printPreviewPages.Add(i, print);
printdocument.AddPages(printPreviewPages[i]);
```

To change the windowing size:
PreferredLaunchViewSize :

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
```

FullScreen mode :

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
```

Please let me know any way to resolve the exception.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just used your posted code, I can't reproduce your problem, my os version is 14393.